# Accessing Doctrine related field from JOIN

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I am attempting to pull a list of users using doctrine, with a join, from my database. I have the following function in my model:

```
public function getAttendees() {
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('a.id, a.name, a.url, m.id')
        ->from('Attendees a')
        ->leftJoin('a.Meetings m WITH m.Meeting_Slot_ID = ?', $this->getId());

    return $q->execute();
}
```

I've checked the SQL generated by this query, and it is gabbing all the data I want. I am now trying to access the data retrieved. I have the following working:

```
foreach($object0>getAttendees() as $attendee){
    echo $attendee->getName();
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to access the m.id field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this:

```
$attendee->getMeetings()->getId()
```

You have to use the alias you defined in your schema.yml (if you are using symfony)
Generally Doctrine uses this way to chain related models together:
model1->model2->model3
...->getModel2()->getModel3()->getModel3Field()

Comment: actually, getMeetings() returns an array of meetings, because this is a one to many relation.

Answer (score 1):

`$attendee->getMeeting()->getId();` OR soemthing to that effect depending on how you have your relations/properties named.